# VBA macro concatenate 2 columns in new column

Tags: excel, vba, string-concatenation

I want to create a macro that inserts new column with column name (BL & Container) and then concatinates 2 column in newly inserted column.
In this column I named BL & Container is a new column added my macro.
Further I want the macro to concatenate the values present in column H and F macro should find column H and F by column name and concatenate the them in to newly inserted column I.

My codes below

```
Sub insert_conc()

Dim ColHe As Range
Dim FindCol As Range
Dim con As String
Dim x As Long


Set FindCol = Range("1:1") 'Looks in entire first row.
Set ColHe = FindCol.Find(what:="BL/AWB/PRO", After:=Cells(1, 1))
  
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WE")

  ColHe.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
  ColHe.Offset(0, 1).Value = "WER"
  'x = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  con = "=H2&""-""&F2"
  ColHe.Resize(x - 1).Formula = con
    
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

[![Error in code][3]][3]

In this code line " con = "=H2&""-""&F2"" please advise how do I update column nameinstead of H2 and F2 macro should find columna H2 and F2 header name and then concatinate the values in newly inserted column I BL & container. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, use the next adapted code:

```
Sub insert_conc()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, x As Long, ColHe As Range
 Dim FindCol As Range, con As String, firstCell As Range

 Set sh = Worksheets("LCL")
 x = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row

 Set FindCol = sh.Range("1:1") 'Looks in entire first row.
 Set ColHe = FindCol.Find(what:="BL/AWB/PRO", After:=sh.cells(1, 1))

  ColHe.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
  ColHe.Offset(0, 1).value = "BL & Container"
  Set firstCell = ColHe.Offset(1, -2) ' determine the cell to replace F2

  con = "=" & ColHe.Offset(1).Address(0, 0) & "&" & firstCell.Address(0, 0)
  ColHe.Offset(1, 1).Resize(x - 1).Formula = con
End Sub
```

It is also good to know that using `With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("LCL")` makes sense only if you use it in the code lines up to `End with`. And your code did not do that... It should be used before, in order to deal with the appropriate sheet, **even if it was  not the active one**.

Comment: it works but while conatinating it should take column H value first and then column F as mentioned screenshot of my desired output. This is conatenating F and H column I want to concatenate H and F column

Comment: @Sandzzzzzzzzzzzzzz Please, refresh the page (this one) and use the code I immediately corrected. I also could see that it does not exactly do what you required...

Comment: its perfect thanks a ton can you please help me understand how did u define column F and H please I am trying to fig it out but I am unable to get it

Comment: @Sandzzzzzzzzzzzzzz I thought it is obvious... `ColHe` is first cell in H:H. `ColHe.Offset(1).Address(0, 0)` means address of the second cell in H:H. `Address(0, 0)` means the relative address ("H2" - able to be incremented). Without `(0, 0)` it would return "$H$2", which is absolute address, not incrementable... The same for the other used one: `ColHe.Offset(1, -2)` means two columns back and a row down ("F2")...